# Spring batch for reading a joined query or multiple tables

Tags: spring-batch

I am developing spring batch job to data from DB2 client and write to a flat file.  I used JdbcCursorItemReader and rowmapper for reading data. But using JdbcCursorItemReader I'm not able to run one to many and other relationship queries. Please suggest some solutions.

Comment: can you share some code with us?

Comment: should be trivial... paste your SQL and Mapper code.